# Java - The method encodeBase64

Tags: java, encoding, base64

I have a String `String x = "Sample text";` and I want to print the base64 encryption of it. As numerous examples mention, I use:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(x.getBytes());
System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));
```

But this gives me `The method encodeBase64(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64`... Why is that?

Comment: What package is your `Base64` from?

Comment: Um? I don't know what that means... I just added `import java.util.Base64;` as suggested =/

Comment: Base64 is not encryption, it is (binary to text) **encoding**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `encode` method is in the `Base64.Encoder` class that you can get by running `Base64.getEncoder()`.

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(x.getBytes());
```

Similarly, to decode:

```
String originalString = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedBytes));
```

Check out [the `Base64` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) for more info.

Comment: If I'm not wrong,  the decode statement above calls the variable 'encodedBytes' like a function 'encodedBytes()'. Please remove the brackets at the end.

Comment: The issue @Ramraj mentioned was fixed by this edit: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29887426/2

Comment: convert encodedBytes to String, just pass in new String() constructor parameter. new String(encodedBytes)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of rewriting the code you should simply include the Apache commons codec module into your classpath. This has the exact method signature, [`Base64.encodeBase64(byte[])`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64-byte:A-). And yes, just hitting "encodeBase64" in an internet search should be enough.

Note that your project may use other functionality from that same codecs package. So you should always first try and find the modules / libraries used by a project before you start replacing the code. And sometimes there are subtle differences between implementations, which could make the project fail in the right circumstances.

That said, the code in the question does of course not make sense. You could use `encodeBase64String` to directly convert to `String` without having to convert to bytes and then to `String`. And for newer level API's there is indeed the `java.util.Base64` class, as mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29887426/589259). Finally - and more importantly - if `x` already contains a string, why would you base 64 encode it?

Answer (score 0):

I kinda solved it but check if it works

**decode.setText(new String(Base64.decode(inputText.getText().toString(), Base64.DEFAULT)));**

Tell me if it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

You could also use:

```
byte[] originalString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedBytes);
```

to decode (this is what I used in a Base64 encoder/decoder applet I recently wrote)