# How to allow the user to download a byte[] or base64 to their chosen directory

Tags: java, image, pdf, base64

I want to allow the user to download a pdf file created in iText.

The expected result is that the user can download the pdf to their selected directory. The actual result is the file will not download.

I am generating a pdf using iText and passing the result back to my ajax call to allow the user to download the file. I have the base64. I checked that it was valid by using https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf This showed the pdf correctly. However, I can not get the result to download in the ajax ".done".

I have tried using:

```
byte[] decoder = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64);
```

Before passing it back; however, I get an error message on ".getDecoder()" of "The method getDecoder() is undefined for the type Base64".

The java code is:

```
resourceImage = MySQLConnection.recipePDF(accountID, crID, servings, servingSize);
String imageDataString = Base64Encode2.encode(resourceImage);
System.out.println("imageDataString: " + imageDataString);

if (resourceImage == null) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "No recipe pdf.");
} else {
    String json = new Gson().toJson(imageDataString);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

The javascript/ajax code on the is:

```
.done(function(responseJson1a){
    dataType: "json";
    alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson1a));  
    download(responseJson1a, "resourcefile.pdf", "application/pdf");
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question/solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29887426/4417924

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer. I needed to add "data:application/pdf;base64," to the start of the string.

```
download("data:application/pdf;base64,"+responseJson1a, "resourcefile.pdf", "application/pdf");
```